# Why was the "Have you considered accept an answer" legend removed?

Tags: discussion

I used to  visually filter my questions using that legend one for those  I haven't pick a correct answer.

I'm glad not to see it on CW's though.

Howcome?

Answer (score 1):

At one time, they reduced it to not show unless the question had been opened a certain number of days, and after 60 days they would stop showing it.  Not sure if your questions fall into that or not.